# Signing HTTP requests with JWS

Tags: http, digital-signature, json, jws

Looking over the spec for [JSON Web Signature](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7515) (JWS), I realise that it doesn't seem to specify anything that is HTTP-specific in terms of the payload. Specifically, signing HTTP headers and bodies (say, so a server can verify certain HTTP headers and the HTTP body were constructed by a client).

Is there some way to use JWS to verify HTTP requests? I could come up with some definition of the JWS payload: some sort of "canonical" combination of HTTP headers and body, but I would have thought this would have already been designed...

Or perhaps, suggest an alternative mechanism.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to do. JWS is a way to ensure the integrity of information and not necessarily bound to http. Could you explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @phisch "JWS is a way to ensure the integrity of information": in this case, verifying both HTTP headers and body received by a server. Will see if I can make this clearer in the question

Comment: I would recommend to use HTTP signing, which sounds more like what you want: https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-cavage-http-signatures-08.html

Comment: @MartinFürholz I came to a similar conclusion! https://github.com/michalc/python-http-signature-client and https://github.com/michalc/python-http-signature-server

Answer (score 1):

There is "Signing HTTP Requests via JSON Web Signatures" https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-richanna-http-jwt-signature-00 that specifies a method [although it has expired].

It seems to require that the JWS payload is JSON [which is not true in general for JWS, I believe]. It adds sha256 hashes to the JSON object. For example, for HTTP headers in a canonicalised string of:

```
content-type: application/json
etag: 742-3u8f34-3r2nvv3
```

that has sha256 `bZA981YJBrPlIzOvplbu3e7ueREXXr38vSkxIBYOaxI`, then it adds to the JSON payload:

```
"h": [["content-type", "etag"], "bZA981YJBrPlIzOvplbu3e7ueREXXr38vSkxIBYOaxI"]
```

I'm not such a crazy fan of this for the facts that it requires certain top-level keys in the JSON payload, and that it requires a JSON payload at all. For example, seems tricky to use this for a large binary payload.